# Why does the order of linked object file with $L directive matter?

Tags: delphi, linker, external

I use statically linked sqlite database and in order to compile every next version I sometimes have to do minor changes in the list of object files used.
But sometimes the changes I have to make puzzles me.
For example prior to version 3_6_10 this order

```
{$L 'Objs\is.OBJ'}
{$L 'Objs\mbisspc.OBJ'}
```

was ok, but starting 3_6_12 the linker said

```
unsatisfied forward or external declaration _isspace
```

but changing the order to

```
{$L 'Objs\mbisspc.OBJ'}
{$L 'Objs\is.OBJ'}
```

helped. 
As for the changes in sqlite, it really stopped to use c function isspace in 3_6_12 and started to use an internal equivalent so "isspace" keyword even don't appear inside the obj file.

So why does the order of linked object file with $L directive matter and where I can read more about this? I suppose it is something related to cross-usage of the listed obj files, but I will feel more safe if I understand what is going on

Thanks

Comment: version 3_6_10 and 3_6_12  of what? I don't know any Delphi versions like that.

Comment: sorry, it was about sqlite versions, just giving more details about ojbect files I used

Comment: @Jeroen: And what version of Delphi do you know that uses obj files? :-) Obviously it is the version of his sqlite library.

Comment: Do I miss something? Obj files linking existed in Delphi for ages, didn't it? )

Comment: @Marjan: sorry, I totally missed the sqllite bit.

Comment: @Jeroen: It happens to all of us :-). @Maksee: obj linking yes, and with proper settings even obj generation. But Delphi does not ship with that many obj's in its library... A couple at most and those aren't very well known and certainly don't have the names mentioned by the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

As of the comment by [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) linking to [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638186/error-while-linking-multiple-c-object-files-in-delphi-2007/4638633#4638633) to this other [question on linking .obj file in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638186/error-while-linking-multiple-c-object-files-in-delphi-2007), I replaced `linker` by `compiler`, and added a the *italic* portion below:

C compilers use a multi-pass <strike>linker</strike> compiler that knows how to resolve forward and circular dependencies between .obj files.

Since the Delphi <strike>linker</strike> compiler is targeted at the Delphi language, and the Delphi language does not allow for that, the <strike>linker</strike> compiler does not allow for this either.

Pro: the <strike>linker</strike> compiler is much faster.

Con: you need to help the <strike>linker</strike> compiler a bit by placing the .obj files in the right order
*, or by manually resolving the dependencies (see the above mentioned [answer by David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638186/error-while-linking-multiple-c-object-files-in-delphi-2007/4638633#4638633))* 
.

--jeroen

Comment: So from what you said, I conclude that there might be a situation when Delphi 1-pass linker won't be able to link if the references are circular?

Comment: @Maksee: I think that is indeed possible. I'm not sure if the Borland C++ Linker works around this in any way.

Comment: @Jeroen since the C++ linker is linking C++, surely it would have to deal with circular references?

Comment: @Jeroen I think you answer should actually refer to the compiler rather than the linker. Surely it's the compiler that is single pass. The linker has to be multi-pass. First pass to concatenate the objects and build the map. Second pass to fixup all the function addresses.

Comment: @David: I think the fix-ups are done at link time. Barry Kelly or Danny Thorpe would be the guys with the ultimate answer for this :-)

Comment: @Jeroen These issues are all at compile time; you can see that because the error is reported when compiling rather than linking.  I have found that declaring the missing forward/external reference as an external procedure is enough to get the compile to succeed. I'm guessing that doing so tells the compiler to write a JMP/CALL that will be resolved at link fixup time. See http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638186/error-while-linking-multiple-c-object-files-in-delphi-2007

Comment: @Jeroen @Maksee all this gives a way to get round any problems with circular references.